# REFERENCE ON COMPOSITE PRIMARY KEY

Tags: sql, sql-server

My data is in the tables (This is an example):

BOX
[image]

And the BOX CONTENT Table:
[image]

And every box in the system will be like that. Because one box must have:
CLIENT CODE,
BOX CODE
AND BOX NUM

And every item in the box must have:
CLIENT CODE,
BOX CODE,
BOX NUM
AND ONE NUMBER FOR EVERY ITEM.

Now, for this I make composite primary key on both tables:

```
CREATE TABLE BOX ( 
CLIENT_CODE NVARCHAR(10), 
BOX_CODE Nvarchar(50),
BOX_NUMBER SMALLINT, 
BOX_CONTENT NVARCHAR(250), 
CONSTRAINT PK_BOX_CLI_COD_NUM PRIMARY KEY(CLIENT_CODE, BOX_CODE, BOX_NUMBER)
);
```

and

```
CREATE TABLE BOX_CONTENT ( 
CLIENT_CODE NVARCHAR(10), 
BOX_CODE Nvarchar(50),
BOX_NUMBER SMALLINT, 
BOX_CONTENT_NUMBER SMALLINT, 
ID1 NVARCHAR(50),
ID2 NVARCHAR(50),
ID3 NVARCHAR(50),
ID4 NVARCHAR(50)
CONSTRAINT PK_BOXCONT_CLI_COD_BNUM_CNUM PRIMARY KEY(CLIENT_CODE, BOX_CODE, BOX_NUMBER, BOX_CONTENT_NUMBER)
);
```

My question is, How can I reference the FOREIGN KEYS between the tables?
this tables will have a lot of data and need references.

If I do this:

```
CONSTRAINT fk_BOX_CLI FOREIGN KEY(CLIENT_CODE) REFERENCES BOX(CLIENT_CODE),
CONSTRAINT fk_BOX_CODE FOREIGN KEY(BOX_CODE) REFERENCES  BOX(BOX_CODE),
CONSTRAINT fk_BOX_NUMB FOREIGN KEY(BOX_NUMBER) REFERENCES BOX(BOX_NUMBER)
```

I have an error, If I set the FK in one single line too.

Anybody has an idea please?
It will be appreciated...

Best Regards...

Comment: Please take the time to replace the pictures (link) with the actual text. It doesn't look that complicated.

Comment: And  lowercase the capital title

Comment: Thanks Royi,
But when I tried it, Tabs and spaces misaligned text.
So, I inserted image links for showing better what I have and What I need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to put the constraint in a single reference:

```
CONSTRAINT fk_BOX FOREIGN KEY(CLIENT_CODE, BOX_CODE, BOX_NUMBER)
    REFERENCES BOX(CLIENT_CODE, BOX_CODE, BOX_NUMBER)
```

However, I would encourage you to put an identity int primary key on `BOX`, and use that for a foreign key reference.  You can declare a `UNIQUE` constraint on `BOX(CLIENT_CODE, BOX_CODE, BOX_NUMBER)` to prevent duplicates.